# Water flow sensor stays on until tapped

Tags: switches, sensor, components, hall-effect

I'm using a hall effect rotor sensor to control power to a UV purifier connected to the outflow from a reverse osmosis undersink tank system, connected to the inflow of the UV purifier chamber.
([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07DM1X4SL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DM1X4SL))
[image]

**My problem is that it won't turn off on its own unless tapped/smacked**. Did I just get a bad sensor or is there something I didn't account for? Is the pressure in the system keeping the switch from disengaging? Would a different orientation, or placing it downstream of the UV chamber help? What am I missing? It is installed with the correct orientation to flow.

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts as an electrical engineering question....

Comment: `My problem is that it won't turn off on its own` ... why is that a problem? ... shouldn't you be looking for transitions, not steady state signal?

Comment: @jsotola If it doesn't turn off, that means you're lacking a high-to-low transition that should be there. And if there's no high-to-low transition, there can't be a subsequent low-to-high transition.

Comment: @Hearth I'm reading it as `it stays on when the water flow stops` ... if it's a rotary sensor then it can stop at either state

Answer (score 2):

If this is a flow *sensor* it will have a pulse output which has to be dealt with.  Interior mechanism is likely a paddle wheel with embedded magnet and a Hall pickup (3 wires with polarity) or possibly a reed capsule (two wires, no polarity).

If it is a flow *switch* it will have a paddle internally that reacts to liquid flow and a similar type of pickup. The difference is that with flow you will get a switch transition that is maintained so long as the flow is sufficient to operate it, as opposed to a train of pulses.

If it is "sticking" it is likely that either the paddle is mechanically sticking or (if it's a reed capsule) it's been overloaded and the contacts are damaged and are sticking. It the latter case, you may need to replace the unit and create a circuit that does not overload the reed switch.